# Input and dropdown have different values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an bootstrap datetimepicker. I set the defaults but input and dropdown have different values.

You can see printscreen from the link : http://prntscr.com/i172wq

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group ">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.dTarih, new { @class = "col-md-3  control-label" })
 <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="input-group date formDateTime" id="formDateTime">
         @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.dTarih, new { @Class = "form-control input-datetime", id = "talept", @readonly = "", size = "16" })
         @*<input size="16" readonly="" class="form-control" type="text">*@
         <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button class="btn default date-set" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
         </span>
     </div>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
 $('.formDateTime').datetimepicker({
    isRTL: false,
    format: 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:ii',
    autoclose: true,
    language: 'tr',
    defaultDate: new Date()
});
```

How can I set correct values both of them?

Comment: ["Can someone help me?" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/162698)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you need to initialize timepicker on the `<input>`, not on the `<div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, `formDateTime` is associated to a **DIV** while it should be associated to your **INPUT**. Secondly, to set a default value you can use:

**HTML:**

```
:
<input class="form-control" type="date" id="formDateTime">
:
```

**JS:**

```
$("#formDateTime").val = new Date() ;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I add type = "date" to input it seems like this : http://prntscr.com/i1jsr9 . I can't change the value with popup.

Comment: I can't access pictures (company policy). The `type="date"` can be used (not mandatory though) to get the standard browser element to pick dates. You may use a simple `text` type instead. Up to you what would best fit you needs.

Comment: I added to razor textboxfor  `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.dTarih, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm}", new { @Class = "form-control input-datetime", id = "talept", @readonly = "", size = "16", @type = "text" })` datetime format and type=text and it is working now. It is associated to a div also.

Comment: @GörkemYazıcı, be careful when naming elements. If you give the same ID to more than one single element, the application might run with inconsistent behavior (specially when using different browsers). Besides, it is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

defaultDate: moment().hours(0).minutes(0)